# Mac 10.6 - Unable to cp and mv files into ~/Library/Screen Savers/

Tags: macos, mac, screensaver, cp, mv

I am trying to use Terminal to copy a file into ~/Library/Screen Savers/, but every time I try to do it, it fails.

My command is:

```
cp -r Web.saver '~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver'
```

and the result is:

```
cp: ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver: No such file or directory
cp: Web.saver: unable to copy extended attributes to ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver: No such file or directory
cp: ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver/Contents: No such file or directory
cp: Web.saver/Contents: unable to copy extended attributes to ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver/Contents: No such file or directory
cp: ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver/Contents/MacOS: No such file or directory
cp: Web.saver/Contents/MacOS: unable to copy extended attributes to ~/Library/Screen
```

and so on for every file inside the file Web.saver

if I do

```
mv Web.saver '~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver'
```

then is says:

```
mv: rename Web.saver to ~/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver: No such file or directory
```

Even though ~/Library/Screen Savers/ does exist.

Can someone tell me how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde doesn't work inside quotation marks (see [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/how-to-cd-to-a-directory-with-a-name-containing-spaces-in-bash))

You can write

```
cp -r Web.saver $HOME"/Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver"
```

or

```
cp -r Web.saver ~/Library/Screen\ Savers/Web.saver
```

or

```
cp -r Web.saver ~/"Library/Screen Savers/Web.saver"
```

Comment: Thanks I was making mistake like
~/Documents/Github Com/used instead of ~/Documents/Github\ Com/used